# PutImageData only draws part of the image to the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

HTML:

```
<img id="img-1" src="test/fixtures/1a.png">
<img id="img-2" src="test/fixtures/1b.png">
<canvas id="myCanvas3" style = "border:solid rgb(300,50,300);"> </canvas>
<button id="diff">Difference </button>
```

Javascript:

```
 pixelmatch(img1.data, img2.data, diff.data, width, height, {threshold: 0.1});
 ctx3.putImageData(diff, 0, 0);
```

Where img1 and img2 are the image data from the pictures on the website and width an height their dimensions. So the problem I have i that putImageData somehow does not put the whole image into the canvas.

[image]

Asyou can see here the images have the same dimensions in the image data. But the result I get after putting the image data on the canvas is:

[image]

As you can clearly see from the border the canvas is big enough and the right size but the image is only drawn partially.

Comment: Ensure you are getting the canvas width and height from the element's properties eg `width = canvas.width; height = canvas.height` as this is the resolution of the canvas. If you get the size of the canvas from the style it may not match the canvas resolution as style sets the canvas display size, not the resolution.

Comment: The problem seems to lie in your `pixelmatch` method, which is probably not iterating through all pixels. Even left part is cropped. Please provide an [MCVE].

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?